# How do I perform a static wait in selenium using java?

Tags: java, selenium, thread-sleep, fluentwait, implicitwait

It's pretty frustrating. Everywhere I look people keep telling me to use explicit, implicit, and fluent waits. These waits make it so you pause based on elements. However, patronizing us and removing tools and options is not a good idea. In my current specific pickle, I have a button that is designed to disappear if someone clicks on it too quickly. However, it is also designed to now show up immediately either. So you have to wait until it shows up, then wait for enough time to pass by, and only then click the button. With the suggestions, I am given it is impossible. A static *pause* or *sleep* has to be used in this case. For some reason, I can't even use thread sleep because it seems like it has been deprecated in Java 8 itself or something.

Comment: Does anything changes in the html between the button appearance and the button being eligible for click? and why do you think `Thrrad.sleep()` is deprecated in Java 8?

Comment: I would suggest an explicit wait to wait for the button to appear, then a Thread.sleep to wait for the the minimal amount of time needed to ensure the it has not been clicked too quickly and does not disappear in this specific scenario

Comment: Also Java 8 docs for Thread.sleep (it's not deprecated) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-  Would be good to have more details of the error you are seeing, to help you with the Thread.sleep part of the problem

Answer (score 0):

implicit Wait:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TimeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Explicit Wait:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriverRefrence,TimeOut);
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the source that makes you think, that [java.lang.Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) would be deprecated?

So even in the [Java 11 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) it is not deprecated.

So if you want to use it, feel free. :-)

Comment: I can't seem to make the command stop erroring no matter what imports i use.

Comment: Please show the imports you are using and the corresponding error messages and deprecation warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly through the terms *static wait* and *static pause* you meant [`Thread.sleep()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) which is still useful in many ways.

However, while executing your *Tests* through *Selenium* inducing *sleep* wouldn't be an elegant solution to fix the issue as inducing `Thread.sleep(1000);` degrades the overall **Test Execution Performance**. You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium needs a sleep before going to the next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45087766/selenium-needs-a-sleep-before-going-to-the-next-page/45095807#45095807).

If you need to induce *waits* [Implicit Waits](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits) is a good way to start with. You can find a detailed discussion in [Using implicit wait in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672693/using-implicit-wait-in-selenium/45674706#45674706). However as the current *Web Applications* are built through [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/), [Angular](https://angular.io/), [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/), etc **Explicit Waits** would be the way forward.

So, moving forward you can make a transition towards [Explicit Waits](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits). You can find a detailed discussion in [Replace implicit wait with explicit wait (selenium webdriver & java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712431/replace-implicit-wait-with-explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-java/45715759#45715759).

At this point, implementing [Fluent Wait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) will be much easier and you can find a detailed discussion in [Implicit vs Explicit vs Fluent Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145111/implicit-vs-explicit-vs-fluent-wait/48162909#48162909).

Comment: Using `Thread.sleep()` to wait for elements, etc. is not a good practice but if you need to time something specific on the page as OP is, it's fine to use. Using implicit waits is NOT a best practice per the Selenium contributors, as I've mentioned before. Explicit waits and Fluent waits are basically the same, Explicit waits are just prepackaged waits and both are "best practice" waits.

Comment: +1 never use implicit waits, always use explicit ones (explicit waits are built on top of fluent waits, I agree they are the same thing for all intents and purposes.  A fluent wait is just an explicit wait with some additional config options)